# Copy 100s of Excel Graphs from one Worksheet to PowerPoint in C#

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, powerpoint

I'm attempting to copy excel graphs to excel. It works fine for the first 10, then it doesn't work for the rest. Any suggestions for how to fix it are appreciated.

```
// create excel spreadsheet and populate
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application appExl = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();// .ApplicationClass();
// add tons of data and create a bunch of graphs
// <... c# stuff ...>
appExl.Visible = true; // shows correct excel spreadsheet populated with all my graphs


// open powerpoint from template containing exactly 1 blank slide
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application appPpt = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
string pPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Encompass\Sdk\Samples\C#\CustomProjects\PowerPointTemplates\blankPowerPoint.potx";

Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation presentation = appPpt.Presentations.Open(pPath, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slides slides = presentation.Slides;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObjects chartObjects = worksheet.ChartObjects(Missing.Value) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObjects;
Console.WriteLine("chart objects count: " + chartObjects.Count);

for (int i = 0; i < chartObjects.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("6." + i.ToString() + ".1");
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.CustomLayout customLayout = presentation.Slides[1].CustomLayout;
    Console.WriteLine("6." + i.ToString() + ".2");
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide slide = slides.AddSlide(i + 2, customLayout);
    Console.WriteLine("6." + i.ToString() + ".3");
    slide.Layout = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank;
    Console.WriteLine("6." + i.ToString() + ".4");
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject existingChartObject = chartObjects.Item(i + 1) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject;
    Console.WriteLine("6." + i.ToString() + ".5"); // <-- last output here on the 11th iteration (starts at 0), thus it errors on the '.Copy()'
    existingChartObject.Copy(); 
    Console.WriteLine("6." + i.ToString() + ".6");
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ShapeRange shapeRange = slide.Shapes.Paste();//Paste it to your Current Slide
    Console.WriteLine("6." + i.ToString() + ".7");

    // move copied graphs to the upper left corner of the powerpoint slide
    shapeRange.Left = 0;
    shapeRange.Top = 0;

    // reshape copied graphs to size of powerpoint slide
    shapeRange.Width = 960;
    shapeRange.Height = 540;
    Console.WriteLine("6." + i.ToString() + ".8");
}

appPpt.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
```

I end up with a powerpoint that is populated with the first 10 graphs on slides 2-11, and slide 1 and slide 12 are blank. I would like to have all 123 graphs in the powerpoint on separate slides rather than just the first 10, ideas where I went wrong?

Output:

```
chart objects count: 123
6.0.1
6.0.2
6.0.3
6.0.4
6.0.5
6.0.6
6.0.7
6.0.8
6.1.1
6.1.2
<...>
6.8.4
6.8.5
6.8.6
6.8.7
6.8.8
6.9.1
6.9.2
6.9.3
6.9.4
6.9.5
6.9.6
6.9.7
6.9.8
6.10.1
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
6.10.2
6.10.3
6.10.4
6.10.5
A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
```

I think these runtime errors indicate that I'm accessing objects that have been deleted? but how could that be if they exist in the excel spreadsheet and I'm accessing from the 'chartObject' that is connected to the excel worksheet?

Comment: I would not use interop if possible.  There are several free libraries out there that would help you do this much better and easier.  My personal favorite is closedXML.

Comment: @samstarobin, what's your reasoning? It's seemed to work pretty well for me so far

Comment: it was never really designed for any mass operations.  If you ever have to take it to production  you'll have to keep an open session on a server since it can't be run as a background process.  Memory leaks abound if you don't do it exactly right and even if you do.